# how to pass in a Map of unknown structure/type

Tags: java, json

I want to have some Map that contains either

```
<String, String> 
<String, Map<String, String>> 
<String, Map<String, String[]>>
```

So far I have the following:

```
Map<String, ?> any = new HashMap<String, ?>();
```

When I retrieve the values I want to do something like if values instanceof String[], but this does not work because generics are removed at runtime. Is the way I approach dealing with the random structure incorrect?

What are some viable options. I am currently attempting to do something like..

```
values.get(0) instanceof String[]
```

Feels kind of ...wrong, any input?

EDIT: I have a map for each type of json structure I want to deal with as a java bean

```
class JAVABEAN{
    Map<String, String[]> structure1;
    Map<String, Map<String, String>> structure2;
    Map<String, ?> anyStructure;
}
```

anyStructure can have either structure1 or structure2 in it, it contains any combination(I have more than 2 structures in my actual project).

Based on the map the items are in, I call a different methods to handle the data..

```
for(each item in javabean)
    if structure1, call method1..
    if structure2, call method2..
    if anyStructure, call method1 or method2
```

Sometimes anyStructure will not be used at all, but there will always be at least 1 structure1 or structure2

EDIT2: This is a service called from a rest service, which deals json currently. I take in a json that gets converted to java for me through jersey, I believe the json has to be simple for this conversion(no interfaces) which is why I use Map instead of something like RangeQuery which will have a String and String[] member.

Comment: You'd have to use a `Map<String, Object>` and `instanceof` but that's probably a bad design. Maybe if you told us about the problem you are trying to solve we can suggest a better way to approach it.

Comment: If your values don't have any common interface, and their only common ancestor is Object, all you can do is use a `Map<String, Object>` and use `instanceof`. You should probably wrap the values in some adapter classes which share a common interface.

Comment: Why do you want to store these different kinds of maps in the same location?  What could you do with all these different kinds of data?  It sounds like these should be stored differently and treated differently.

Comment: Have you considered creating classes that are annotated using JAXB and specifically created to handle the different forms your data may appear in? That way, if the JSON data unmarshals into a particular type, you can embed your special behavior into that class directly, rather than figure it out based on the structure of the data.

Comment: I have the json turning into a java bean through jersey, basically the example I provided is kind of what the bean looks like. It contains a map for each type of structure coming in, based on the structure I perform certain actions.

Comment: @Louis, I am creating a query based on key and value pairs, the location of these should be 1 class that I can pass through a service giving me all the data I need in 1 call. Depending on the structure of the map, I know which query operator to use, example.. if structure1 use an IN operator, if structure2 use range operator.

Comment: Then it sounds like you should have a `Query` interface with several implementations, one for range queries, one for in queries, etc.  That would be the proper way to deal with a problem like that.

Comment: hmm I wonder if jersey will automatically convert json to bean for me if I use interfaces like that, I used simple Map<String, String> instead of RangeQuery because I think jersey only handles basic structures

Comment: Take a look at this simple example using JAXB. You might find it's a little more extensible than Jersey. http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/xml/bind/jaxb-json-example/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, I see your problem. **Just use a JSON library**. Gson or Jackson. Use JSON objects to hold this together instead of trying to rip apart JSON into the ostensible Java equivalents, `Map<String, Map<String, String[]>[]` and such complex nonsense.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but there is more to my problem then that, I can't say everything because its work related, but there is a good reason for my java implementation. I can have more than 1 structure using the same data structure, but for different queries. Map<String, String[]> can be used for 2 different queries, the easiest way to know which for me to use, is to have the front end know which javascript object to put it under. I think maybe I could be wrong and I can make my bean use interfaces, i wil have to check it out

Comment: @CatznDogz don't reuse things that aren't reusable.

Comment: @CatznDogz But you came here because what you found is that the design is actually awkward to use.

Comment: I decided I can use interfaces instead of Maps, it was working when I just tested having jersey automatically convert, thanks everyone